# difference in std::shared_ptr between windows and native android

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am using a vector of shared pointers to custom objects as below:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> Things;
void Foo()
{
   std::shared_ptr<Thing> newThing(std::make_shared<Thing>());
   //do something with newThing
   Things.push_back(newThing)
}
```

In some other function `Bar`, I am trying to access the raw pointer from newThing as such with no issues:

```
void Bar()
{
   Things.at(index).get();
}
```

But, since the scope of the shared pointer `newThing` is lost after exiting `foo()`, the destructor of the `Thing` object should be called and the operation in `Bar` should lead to a segfault. How am I still able to access this?

Comment: `Things.push_back(newThing);` makes a copy of `newThing`. The lifetime of `newThing` has no impact on the lifetime of it's copy within `Things`.

Comment: What is the difference in Windows vs Android??

Comment: The *purpose* of `std::shared_ptr<T>` is that the shared instance of `T` is only deleted when the last `std::shared_ptr<T>` to that instance is destroyed. As long as at least one copy of the `shared_ptr` exists, it will also continue of the to exist.

Comment: Please format your code and sentences properly, and don't randomly change variable/type names as you go. Get into the habit of being precise, correct, accurate and neat. Take care over what you write.

Comment: @boundaryimposition thanks for your comment. I am new to stackoverflow. Will keep that in mind in future posts.

Answer (score 3):

> since the scope of shared pointer `newThing` is lost after exiting `foo()`

Yeah, but the element in `Things` is a copy of that shared pointer.

> The destructor of the `Thing` object should be called

No. The copied `shared_ptr` inside the vector holds another "reference" to the original `Thing` object, so the original `Thing` object still exists too.

**This is the whole point of `shared_ptr`.**

You really shouldn't use a thing without understanding what it is and what it does.

> The operation in `Bar` should lead to a segfault.

No. Even if your code were wrong and you had undefined behaviour, *you cannot guarantee a segmentation fault*. You should get out of the habit of ever "expecting" a segmentation fault.

> How am I still able to access this?

Because your code is fine, on both Windows and Android.

Answer (score 0):

When `Foo` exits `newThing` gets deleted. At that point `newThing` points to a `Thing` and has ref count of 2 (the other reference is held by the vector `Things`). When `newThing` inside `Foo` gets deleted it will decrement ref count to 1 and when you call `Bar` it will access that existing object inside vector `Things`.

Comment: The vector does not hold a reference. One of its elements does.